# Why does the NetBeans Java debugger never reach this code?

Tags: java, hibernate, debugging, netbeans

I'm trying to debug a method in Java using NetBeans.

That method is:

```
    public Integer getNumberOfClamps(Locations paLocation) {
        Integer ret = -1;
        List list = new ArrayList();

        String removeme = "ABC";

        if (paLocation == null) {
            return ret;
        }

        try {
            IO io = new IO(this.getSchemaName());
            Session session = io.getSession();

            String sql = "select count(*) from assets a join assettypes at on (at.id = a.assettype_id) ";
            sql += "where a.currentlocation_id = " + paLocation.getId() + " and at.clamp = 1 and at.active = 1;";
            list = session.createQuery(sql).list();

            // for some reason, list is empty yet MySQL reports 40 records
            // and the following two lines are never reached!
            ret = list.size();
            removeme = "WHAT???";

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ret = -1;  // explicitly set return
        } finally {
            return ret;
        }
    }
```

Towards the middle of the method you will see `list = session.createQuery(sql).list();`

For some reason, this is returning an empty list even though when the SQL is run manually, I get 40 results.

But the odd part is that once the `.list()` is called, it jumps to the `finally` block and never reaches the rest!  So for testing, 'removeme' should equal `WHAT???` but the debugger reports it as still `ABC`.

What gives?

Comment: Are you *sure* it isn't going through the catch block? It certainly sounds like an exception is being thrown...

Comment: this is terrible exception handling, you are eating any exception so how are you supposed to know what happened, at least print out the stacktrace!

Comment: @JonSkeet absolutely sure.  I had other code in the exception block.  What you see is just a slimmed down example.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson This isn't the entire method.  Only slimmed down for example.  But I am curious.  If I have a method:  `getNumberOfRecords` and I JUST need to know how many records are returned and I don't care about handling an exception, what is wrong with returning a `-1` and letting another method handle that?  Like:  `if(getNumberOfRecords() > 0) { .....`?  What's wrong with that?

Comment: Are you willing to catch Throwable instead of Exception? Something seems fishy.

Comment: If the two lines after you populate the list are never reached, how do you know the list returned is empty??? The list probably is still the empty ArrayList you've created at the beginning (why don't you just declare the list where you use it, and are you using Java 1.4 still - with no type for the list?)... just print the list after you get it, if nothing is printed you know for sure it's an Exception being thrown (agreeing with the comment above, just use printStackTrace() ).

Comment: @Renato well, I know it's empty because when I hover over it, NB reports `[]`.  But it turned out I was using the wrong method.  But I still don't understand why the remaining code wasn't reached.  I could put better exception handling in there but being a C# and Ruby developer (just learning Java), I will have to save that for another day.

Comment: The debugger was showing you the ArrayList you had created earlier, the call to list() was throwing an Exception that the debugger probably failed to show to you for some reason, and list was never re-allocated... don't use debuggers, just print values and stack traces and you will be happier.

Comment: @Renato thanks.  That makes sense.  The reason I stick with the debugger is that I step through the code a lot and when I got to this point, it looked like an exception was thrown but the debugger didn't see it.  Seems pretty weak to me.

Comment: Sorry, but just one more thing if it's ok: don't use Integer (instead of int) unless you have some cases where you could return null.... which does not seem the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong method.  'createQuery' is expecting HQL syntax.  Change your method to 'createSQLQuery'

Comment: Absolutely nailed it.  I didn't catch that.  I changed it to createSQLQuery and I got the 40 like I expected.  Thanks!

Comment: @cbmeeks: Put that doesn't explain what was going on... and you should investigate that. I strongly suspect an exception *was* being thrown - or you were debugging the wrong version of the code, somehow. Java *doesn't* just skip over code like that.

Comment: @JonSkeet right.  I think the debugger was the real culprit here.  Blaming Java was probably a little too harsh.  lol